I want to create a loop to replace the code shown
I have created a variable for Hours but want to loop to go through the the txtTot and Hrs text boxes in user form using For i = 1 to 10
txtTot1.value = Format(Val(Hrs1) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot2.value = Format(Val(Hrs2) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot3.value = Format(Val(Hrs3) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot4.value = Format(Val(Hrs4) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot5.value = Format(Val(Hrs5) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot6.value = Format(Val(Hrs6) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot7.value = Format(Val(Hrs7) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot8.value = Format(Val(Hrs8) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot9.value = Format(Val(Hrs9) * Hours, "0.00")
txtTot10.value = Format(Val(Hrs10) * Hours, "0.00")


Use an array instead of separate Hrs variables, and put the Txt objects into an array. Then you can loop through the arrays using a numeric index. You can search this site for vba array to get examples of how to do so.

Store Multiple Objects in One Variable Using the Array Function

Docs: Array Function

User Form Module: Array
Private Sub PopulateTotalsArray()
    
    Dim InHours() As Variant: InHours = VBA.Array( _
        Hrs1, Hrs2, Hrs3, Hrs4, Hrs5, _
        Hrs6, Hrs7, Hrs8, Hrs9, Hrs10)

    Dim OutTotals() As Variant: OutTotals = VBA.Array( _
        txtTot1, txtTot2, txtTot3, txtTot4, txtTot5, _
        txtTot6, txtTot7, txtTot8, txtTot9, txtTot10)
     
    Dim Hours As Double: Hours = 12.5 ' <-- e.g.
    
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(InHours)
        OutTotals(i).Text = Format(Val(InHours(i).Text) * Hours, "0.00")
    Next i
    
End Sub

User Form Module: Controls
Private Sub PopulateTotalsControls()
     
    Dim Hours As Double: Hours = 12.5 ' <-- e.g.
    
    Dim i As Long

    With Me
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Controls("txtTot" & i).Text _
                = Format(Val(.Controls("Hrs" & i).Text) * Hours, "0.00")
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub

Standard Module (e.g. Module1): Controls

The following can be called from the user form module with
PopulateTotals Me



Sub PopulateTotals(ByVal uf As Object)
     
    Dim Hours As Double: Hours = 12.5 ' <-- e.g.
    
    Dim i As Long

    With uf
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Controls("txtTot" & i).Text _
                = Format(Val(.Controls("Hrs" & i).Text) * Hours, "0.00")
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub


You're going to need to do something like this:
Dim txtTots() As TextBox
Dim Hrss() As String

txtTots = Array(txtTot1, txtTot2, txtTot2, txtTot3, txtTot4, txtTot5, txtTot6, txtTot7, txtTot8, txtTot9, txtTot10)
Hrss = Array(Hrs1, Hrs2, Hrs2, Hrs3, Hrs4, Hrs5, Hrs6, Hrs7, Hrs8, Hrs9, Hrs10)

For i = 1 To 10
    txtTots(i).Text = Format(Val(Hrss(i)) * Hours, "0.00")
Next

